# Have GANs been used to solve regression problems?

Tags: machine-learning, applications, research, generative-adversarial-networks, regression

I've noticed that in the last 2 years [GANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network) have become really popular. I know that initially they have been proposed for image classification but I was curious if any of you are aware of any papers where GANs are used to solve regression problems?

Answer (score 3):

In reality GANs are not made for image classification, but for data generation, and they have gained popularity on image generation. They are also used for tabular data generation, see for example [TGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.00503), or for time series generation, e.g. [Quant GAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06673). You have even some application for the field of graphs and networking, e.g. [NetGAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.00816.pdf) and [GraphGAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08267.pdf).